# Comparator al ordenar afecta todas las listas

Tags: android

En corto seria :

```
public class TabProchesFragment extends Fragment   {

    private static final String TAG = "TabProchesFragment";

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter_Restaurant_MasProximos mRecyclerViewAdapterAccueil;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    List<Restaurant> restauranes = new ArrayList<>();
    Double latitud;
    Double longitud;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabproches_fragment,container,false);

       Bundle bundle = getArguments();

       layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
       mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvRestaurantsProches);
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

       restauranes= (List<Restaurant>) bundle.getSerializable("restauranes");


       if (restauranes!=null) {
            latitud = bundle.getDouble("latitud");
            longitud = bundle.getDouble("longitud");
            Collections.sort(restauranes, new Comparator<Restaurant>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Restaurant o1, Restaurant o2) {
                    return o1.tomarDistancia(latitud,longitud).compareTo(o2.tomarDistancia(latitud,longitud));
                }
           });
       }

       mRecyclerViewAdapterAccueil = new RecyclerViewAdapter_Restaurant_MasProximos(restauranes,latitud,longitud);
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapterAccueil);

       return view;
    }

}
```

Y el otro:

```
public class TabPromotionFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter_Restaurant_MejorPromocion mRecyclerViewAdapterAccueil;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    List<Restaurant> restauranes = new ArrayList<>();
    Double latitud;
    Double longitud;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabpromotion_fragment,container,false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        restauranes= (List<Restaurant>) bundle.getSerializable("restauranes");
        if (restauranes!=null) {
            latitud = bundle.getDouble("latitud");
            longitud = bundle.getDouble("longitud");
            Collections.sort(restauranes, new Comparator<Restaurant>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Restaurant o1, Restaurant o2) {
                     return o2.tomarPromocion() - o1.tomarPromocion();
                }
            });
        }

        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvRestaurantsPromotion);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerViewAdapterAccueil = new RecyclerViewAdapter_Restaurant_MejorPromocion(restauranes,latitud,longitud);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapterAccueil);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Tengo estos dos fragmentos, paso la lista que obtengo a una lista dentro del fragment y despues ordeno la lista con un Comparator, el problema es que lo que ordene en la primera, se ordena en la segunda , pero no comparten el mismo adapter, ni se vuelve un fragmento duplicado, son dos fragmentos que se muestran bien, pero la lista que les paso, termina estando ordenada como una de las 2 formas. Pero no de las 2 formas por separado. Estoy ordenando uno por distancia y otro por promoción .

Ambas se quedan ordenadas por distancia.

Pongo más código de como paso los datos si lo necesitan :

```
restauranes=rowListItem;
RestauranesPageAdapter adapter = new RestauranesPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
abProchesFragment tabProchesFragment = new TabProchesFragment();
TabPromotionFragment tabPromotionFragment= new TabPromotionFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("restauranes", (Serializable) rowListItem);
bundle.putDouble("latitud",latitud);
bundle.putDouble("longitud",longitud);
tabProchesFragment.setArguments(bundle);
tabPromotionFragment.setArguments(bundle);

adapter.addFragment(tabProchesFragment);
adapter.addFragment(tabPromotionFragment);
mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: ¿Dices que guardando una referencia individual (en cada Fragment) de cada lista de objeto y haces un sort de afectan varias?. Intenta pasar tu lista de esta forma en el Bundle: bundle.putParceableListArrayExtra("restauranes", rowListItem); y obtenerla en el Fragment con: restauranes  = bundle.getParcelableArrayExtra("restauranes"); puede ser que serializable deje objetos temporales en el garbage collection. Si no funciona, no entendi tu pregunta o no tengo idea de lo que pasa, saludos.

Comment: Si lo entendiste perfectamente.

Comment: @Andrespengineer No tengo idea de como pasar un objeto tan grande a Parceleable , por eso no lo hice por parceleable , es un objeto sacado de un webservices de como 30 variables , hashmaps , etc.

Comment: Ah entiendo, es decir, ¿Te esta marcando un error de transaction al pasar la data como parceable?, no es lo recomendado pero intenta pasar la data en el constructor de newInstance() del Fragment.

Comment: @Andrespengineer No, sino que tengo entendido que hay que hacer muchas cosas al implementarlo como Parcelable , al intentar haces esas cosas, no se como pasar los Maps , listas , etc , se hace un enrollo , asi que mejor lo pase como Serializable y esta sucediendo que ambas se ordenan igual , a pesar que las estoy ordenando diferente. Hice el debug y en el momento que se ordena 1 , la otra por arte de magia se ordena igual.

Comment: Nunca me ha pasado ese tipo de situación, pero estoy casi seguro que el problema está en Serializable. Trata de indagar y buscar información por ahi a ver como resuelves. Suerte hermano.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Gracias, mas me vale encontrarlo, la aplicación sale en 3 dias! , acabo de preguntar en el ingles.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Lo solucione, era algo super basico, nos fuimos muy lejos, demasiado lejos, buscando el error y el error estaba ante nuestros ojos y es algo que nos enseñan en el primer año de universidad, era la declaracion de la nueva lista, las listas no se clonan como las variables, tenia que declarar la lista de manera diferente , no desde lista= lista ; sino lista<>(lista ) , si no solo hacia referencia a ella , VALGAME DIOS, que perdi mucho tiempo en algo tan ridiculo xD.

Comment: Mira que yo tampoco me fijé jajajaja. Madre mía.

Comment: @Andrespengineer hombre, que la pregunta estubo en el ingles y este desde el viernes y nadie ha sabido llegar a la solución , estando al comienzo del codigo la lista referenciada y no clonada como se debe XD , me llegaron hasta a decir que era la interfaz del comparator y se armo toda una disputa con esta pregunta xD y era algo basico xD , encontre la respuesta de las listas en un foro de hace 8 años.